# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when inserting NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data

I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when inserting an NSManagedObject at the superclass `init` call. The error doesn't always occur, so my guess is that it has something to do with threading, however I'm very new to iOS development so I might be completely wrong.

In the code below I mark the line where the error occurs with a comment.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Measurement)
public class Measurement: NSManagedObject {
    convenience init(sensorId: Int32, fromDatetime: Int64, pm10: Float, pm25: Float, airQualityIndex: Float32, pollutionLevel: Int16,
                     latitude: Double, longitude: Double, source: String, windDeg: Float32, windSpeed: Float32,
                     context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        if let ent = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Measurement", in: context) {
            self.init(entity: ent, insertInto: context) // Thread 10: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffc)
            self.fromDatetime = fromDatetime
            self.pm10 = pm10
            // omitted value asignments
        } else {
            fatalError("Unable to find entity name Measurement")
        }
    }
}
```

The inserting happens after a call to an api inside a for loop.

```
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        // if an error occurs, print it and re-enable the UI
        func displayError(_ error: String) {
            print(error)
        }

        /* GUARD: Was there an error? */
        guard (error == nil) else {
            displayError("There was an error with your request: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        /* GUARD: Did we get a successful 2XX response? */
        guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, statusCode >= 200 && statusCode <= 299 else {
            displayError("Your request returned a status code other than 2xx!")
            return
        }

        /* GUARD: Was there any data returned? */
        guard let data = data else {
            displayError("No data was returned by the request!")
            return
        }

        // parse the data
        let parsedResult: [[String:AnyObject]]!
        do {
            parsedResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
        } catch {
            displayError("Could not parse the data as JSON: '\(data)'")
            return
        }
        let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let stack = delegate.stack
        var counter = 0
        for measurement in parsedResult {

            if counter == 0 {
                print(measurement)
            }

            guard let sensorId = measurement[Constants.MeasurementModelKeys.sensorId] as? Int32 else {
                print("Cannot find key 'sensor_id' in \(measurement)")
                continue
            }

            // other guarded assignments ...

            _ = Measurement(sensorId: sensorId, fromDatetime: fromDatetime, pm10: pm10, pm25: pm25,
                            airQualityIndex: airQualityIndex, pollutionLevel: pollutionLevel, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude,
                            source: source, windDeg: windDeg, windSpeed: windSpeed,
                            context: stack.context) // << this is where the insertion happens

            counter += 1
        }
        print("counter counted: \(counter) elements")

    }

    // start the task!
    task.resume()
}
```

Any help is much appreciated (including tips on how to track down the exact cause of the error).

Comment: Do you see anything in the console ?

Comment: @deadbeef only `(lldb)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is indeed very touchy about threading. Inserting new objects in a context should be performed on that context queue.

Try this :

```
stack.context.perform {
    _ = Measurement(sensorId: sensorId, fromDatetime: fromDatetime, pm10: pm10, pm25: pm25,
                    airQualityIndex: airQualityIndex, pollutionLevel: pollutionLevel, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude,
                    source: source, windDeg: windDeg, windSpeed: windSpeed,
                    context: stack.context)
}
```

Note that this is now an asynchronous call. Make sure this doesn't break your code somewhere else.

Comment: It seems now to work every time :) Thank you so much.